# Setting up Passport - LinkedIn OAuth2.0 Strategy; Cannot see Authorization page loaded

Tags: linkedin-api, passport.js

I am new to developing SPA. I have using AngularJS and NodeJS with Passport. I have succesfully implemented the localStrategy.  Now I am trying :    , LinkedInStrategy = require('passport-linkedin-oauth2').Strategy

When I attempt the login request, I receive the following error: 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load

```
"http://localhost:8000/login/linkedin. The request was redirected to       'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?state=SOME%20STATE&respon…  %2Fcallback&scope=r_emailaddress%20r_basicprofile&client_id=7708er3z2xorot'"
```

, which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.

If I manually click on the link it does show me the authorization page;  Also, i notice in LinkedIn that the API request count is going up, but I cannot get the Authorization page to appear?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I had done wrong and wanted to share the correction and solution:

Originally, i was making an $http.get call (using AngularJS) from my  client to my server (NodeJS).  From the server I called the function that called passport.

Instead now I just set the window address $window.location.href = myServerRouteLinkedin

```
   $scope.loginOauth = function (provider) {
        $window.location.href = environment.apiAuthentication + '/login/' + provider;
    }
```

Hopefully, it may help someone else.